# How to create a AWS SWF workflow Programmatically?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, flash

We are building an application where the user can select the activities based on their requirement. So we build a HTML 5 web page for selecting the activities and creating their own workflow. After selecting the required activities and inputs (Data endpoints) we have to Write the logic for building the workflow. How to build a workflow in AWS SWF programmatically and ,convert the JAVA programs to JAR files?